# Two comboboxes and a button

Tags: java, swing

I state that it is the first piece of Java code that I write and googling I have not found anything that can help me.
What I would like to achieve is that, after selecting the year and month, by pressing the button I can read the chosen values and then execute another code

```
public class  ComboTest {
   
   ComboTest(){     
      String[] monthName = {"Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo"};
      String[] yearName = {"2017", "2018", "2019"};
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("All by myself");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      frame.getContentPane();
      LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
      String anno = String.valueOf(today.getYear());
      int meseEn = today.getMonthValue(); // I need an int to get the italian name
      String mese = monthName[meseEn -1];
      

      JComboBox<String> comboMese=new JComboBox<String>(monthName);    
      comboMese.setSelectedItem(mese);
      comboMese.setBounds(10, 15, 90, 18);    
      comboMese.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
            String monthSelected = (String) comboMese.getSelectedItem();
            System.out.println(monthSelected);
            } 
         });

         JComboBox<String> comboAnno=new JComboBox<String>(yearName);    
         comboAnno.setBounds(110, 15, 90, 20);    
         comboAnno.setSelectedItem(anno);
         comboAnno.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
               String annoSelected = (String) comboAnno.getSelectedItem();
               System.out.println(annoSelected);
               }    
            });
        JButton select=new JButton("select");  
            select.setBounds(220,15,80, 20);  
            select.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener(){  
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
               System.out.println("Selected");  
               //System.out.println(monthSelected); //<---- ComboTest.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
               //System.out.println(annoSelected); <----- the same
                }  
               });
      panel.setLayout(null);
      panel.add(comboMese);
      panel.add(comboAnno);
      panel.add(select);
      panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.add(panel);
      frame.setSize(350,100);      
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
      frame.setVisible(true);
      
}

public static void main(String[] args) {  
   new ComboTest();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: First thing - [avoid null layouts in Swing](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/114-avoid-null-layouts-in-swing)

Comment: You need to define your variables as "instance" variables, not "local" variables. Then other methods will be able to access these variables. The `TextDemo` from [How to Use Text Areas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) shows how to use an ActionListener to copy text from a text field to a text area. It will also show proper Swing coding practices. Keep a reference to the Swing tutorial handy for Swing basics.

Comment: It works. Thank  both of you for the quick answer.